# Alternative to deprecated XmlJsonDataFormat in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, xml-to-json

In Apache Camel, I was trying to use XmlJsonDataFormat to do a quick conversion from XML to JSON. However the XMLJSON (http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html) has deprecated so I am not sure what is the best way to do that conversion aside from creating a processor.

Does anyone know of an alternative to XmlJsonDataFormat?

Comment: You can take a look at Dozer. It should be able to convert between XML and JSON.

Comment: I just saw your comment after investigating the combination of jaxb and jackson. I managed to get it working and will keep Dozer in mind as it looks like a quite convenient mapper/converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries, I have managed to get what I need by combining Jaxb and Jackson for unmarshal XML to POJO and then POJO to JSON. As noMad pointed out, I could have tried Dozer (http://camel.apache.org/dozer.html) as well but haven't got time to do so.

```
    JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
    jacksonDataFormat.setPrettyPrint(true);
    jacksonDataFormat.enableFeature(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

    from("file:src/main/resources/xml/in?noop=true").routeId("lixi-to-json-route").
        unmarshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(ApplicationBatch.class))).
        marshal(jacksonDataFormat).
        to("file:src/main/resources/xml/out?fileName=${file:onlyname.noext}.json");
```

Maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This won't compile for me.  Do you still have the project?  It says there are no methods on JacksonDataFormat class

Comment: @OldProgrammer, sorry it's been a while so I don't have the source code. However, did you include all the required dependencies? The error may mean that it could not find the dependency.

Comment: Those who are looking for xml to json in Camel 3.x.x, camel-xj would solve your problem. It did for me. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875136/cant-translate-xml-to-json-with-apache-camel-3-1-0 for more. 

A simple call like will make it happen
to("xj:identity?transformDirection=XML2JSON")