# How to convert XML to JSON in Apache Camel 3

Tags: java, json, xml, apache-camel

I have a bean that returns an XML string, which I want to convert to JSON.

The [XmlJson data format](http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html) appears to be deprecated in Camel 3. What is the best way to convert XML to JSON? There are no POJO classes that can be used as an intermediate representation.

Expected code:

```
rest().post("/hello")
  .route()
    .to("bean:myBean?method=methodThatReturnsXML")
    .unmarshal() // something with XML
    .marshal() // something with JSON
```

or

```
rest().post("/hello")
  .route()
    .to("bean:myBean?method=methodThatReturnsXML")
    .transform() // something
```

Comment: Alternative workaround. Hope this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021738/alternative-to-deprecated-xmljsondataformat-in-apache-camel

Comment: We have used https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/JaxbDataFormat.java, in our project to convert XML response to Json Response.

Comment: @MebinJoe This is basically what I am looking for except that (I believe) I can't use JAXB because I don't have a POJO class.

Comment: I have the same situation here. Did you was able to solve that? If yes, could you share? Thanks

Comment: @Vitor I ended up createn POJO classes as intermediate representation. I found no way to do a direct conversion

Comment: @Cephalopod, same here. I didn't find any way to do that. Created POJO as well. Thanks.